# Firefox 57 (Quantum) Cookies exceptions not working (in Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: firefox, privacy, blacklist, cookie

When trying to add servers to black list I can't get it; I type the domain, click "Block", but nothing is added to the list.

I regret so much for updating Firefox to v57 since it's much worse regarding to privacy issues (seriously), but now that I have it, I would like to be able to at least block some domains so they can't place their cookies in my computer.

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: In response to why this worries me:

I used tu use "Cookie Monster" on previous Firefox versions; it was great, I was able to block cookies by default and allow just the sites I want sooo easily. I used to like Firefox so much because it let me configure me privacy perfectly.

Now, with Firefox 57 it all has changed so much (API doesn't let developers manage cookies issues) that if even the few tools Firefox offers, fail, it's not that Firefox is now worse than before, but it has become even worse (to me) than other browsers.

In short: I don't understand what is Mozilla doing to Firefox, but I don't like it at all.

Comment: Which blacklist are you referring to ? For me, this seems to work: Go to the website / host you want to block, click the (i) icon at the left of the address bar, then the right arrow thing (>), then "More information", and then set Cookies to "Block" under permissions.

Comment: Edit -> Preferences -> Privacy & Security -> History -> Cookies-Exceptions.
Doesn't work for me as I explained.

Comment: Take a look at [Block websites from storing site preferences or login status in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/block-websites-storing-site-preferences). It doesn't seem so logical based on the window displays, but it seems that you set the cookie permissions in Page Info, and check (and possibly modify) them in the Exceptions dialog. "Type the **exact** address of the site you want to **manage**" seems to confirm this, though I have not tried it.

Comment: Hi user3169, I'm aware of that; I'm not asking about each site permissions but about the Blacklist: it doesn't work for me.

Comment: OK I tried it and it works as you said. But I would only expect operation as defined in help articles. It is misleading though, so you might want to file a bug report.

Comment: By the way, is there a specific reason why you want to add web addresses in the Exceptions dialog box, such as not wanting to actually load such a website? You should add such reasoning to your question.

Comment: I answered you by editing my post, but essentially: If you put a tool in your software, it should work; specially if you are not a 10 yo child developing your own software, but Mozilla...

Comment: Bottom line is that you are the customer so it's your choice. I would consider a bug report for this, to at least get the matter discussed. Perhaps the UI just got ahead of the internals.

Comment: It might be this bug: [Bug 1412627 - Privacy & Security > Accept Cookies > Exceptions... dialog's protocol separation is silly and a UX problem](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1412627). Also see [related bugs](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=cookie+exceptions). Looks like it needs some work...